# Alignment of nodes on d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Please see http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/28. Then click on `query`. Notice how the children start displaying at the same level as `query`. Now pan down to `methods` (a child of `query`) and click this one to expand it. Note how the children of `method` expand differently, almost from the center. This seems to be the behaviour when there are no more children.

How can I get these children to expand the same way that the children of `query` expand?

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the following code (I think), but I still can't find the culprit. I just can't see how the last set of children would be different.

```js
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
links = tree.links(nodes);

nodes.forEach(function(d) { //iterate through the nodes
  if(d.parent){ //if the node has a parent
    for(var i = 0; i < d.parent.children.length; i++){ //check parent children
      if(d.parent.children[i].name == d.name){ //find current node
        d.yOffset = i; //index is how far node must be moved down
        d.parentYoffset = d.parent.yOffset; //must also account for parent downset
      }
    }
  }
  if(d.yOffset === undefined){ d.yOffset = 0; }
  if(d.parentYoffset === undefined){ d.parentYoffset = 0; }
  d.x = (d.yOffset * 40) + (d.parentYoffset * 40) + 20;
  d.y = d.depth * 200;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each new level of nodes you account for the y offset of the current node from the parent and the y offset of the parent from the grandparent. You don't, however, account for the total yoffset from the top of the graph (or the first node).

Carry the Y offset like this:

```
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
links = tree.links(nodes);

nodes.forEach(function(d) { //iterate through the nodes
  if(d.parent){ //if the node has a parent
    for(var i = 0; i < d.parent.children.length; i++){ //check parent children
      if(d.parent.children[i].name == d.name){ //find current node
        d.yOffset = i; //index is how far node must be moved down
        d.parentYoffset = d.parent.yOffset; //must also account for parent downset

        if (d.parent.parentYoffset) {
            d.parentYoffset += d.parent.parentYoffset;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(d.yOffset === undefined){ d.yOffset = 0; }
  if(d.parentYoffset === undefined){ d.parentYoffset = 0; }
  d.x = (d.yOffset * 40) + (d.parentYoffset * 40) + 20;
  d.y = d.depth * 200;
});
```